# How return the index after filtering data class item

Tags: kotlin, filter

I have a simple data class with single item of Long type.
I have an array of these data classed.
The task is to find item in this list with given value and return its index, otherwise -1

It is easily implemented in imperative style:

```
fun findItem(key: Long): Int {
    for (i in 0 until ORDER - 1) {
        if (itemArray[i]?.value == key) {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

My effort:

```
fun findItem(key: Long): Int {
    val filteredIndex = itemArray
        .filter { it?.value == key }
        .map { it.index }
    return ???
    }
```

"index" is red in "it.index"
Cannot find out which function is supposed to be used.

Comment: What is `ORDER`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `indexOfFirst` which returns the index of the first item which satisfies the given predicate. If the item is not found, it returns `-1`:

```kotlin
itemArray.indexOfFirst { it.value == key }
```

Comment: Sounds like an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @MaksimGolendukhin no problem!